# Remove metadata from 7zip files

Tags: command-line, 7zip

If two files with the same checksum and name but with a different created or modified date are compressed using 7zip, using the same settings, then their checksum will be different. I understand it's because of metadata. Is there any way to tell 7zip to ignore those metadata, so that their checksum will be same regardless of their created or modified date? I don't see any command line option in 7zip to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question. If you pass `-mtm-` to 7zip via command line then it won't write metadata. So regardless of the created or modified date, the checksum will be same. Looks like that switch is not documented but thanks to the author of 7zip Igor, he has mentioned about it here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/61905a4c/#5437

Answer (score 2):

Just have a look at the 7zip documentation and have a look at this:
[7zip check sum](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlNfpzd9Ebs), [How a checksum works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxDVEhLPUSY). From what I know just try removing the metadata before compressing the files

Comment: Thanks but how do I remove meta data via command line? I am using 7zip for patching files so I need to remove those meta data. Couldn't find anything helpful to do so